# Derivative of norm-infinity of vector

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

So I know that $\frac{dX}{dX} = \mathbb{I}$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{I} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is the identity matrix.

Now, what is the following derivative?

$\frac{d|X|_\infty}{dX}$

where $|X|_\infty$ is the norm-infinity, i.e. $|X|_\infty = max(X)$ is a scalar?

Comment: Have you considered the case $n=1$?

Comment: case $n=1$ is sort of a given one now isn't it? I am asking for the case of a vector, not a scalar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's study $n=2$.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\max (|x|,|y|)=\begin{cases}\text{sgn } x,&|x|> |y|,\\0,&|x|<|y|.\end{cases}$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\max (|x|,|y|)=\begin{cases}0,&|x|> |y|,\\\text{sgn }y,&|x|<|y|.\end{cases}$$

$$\nabla \max (|x|,|y|)=\begin{cases}\text{sgn } x\,\vec e_1,&|x|> |y|,\\\text{sgn } y\,\vec e_2,&|x|<|y|.\end{cases}$$

Can you generalize it for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: Shouldn't the inequalities be strict?  The partial derivatives don't exist (or are one-sided) when $|x|=|y|$.

Comment: @ErickWong Hm, I think yes. I'll reflect it in my post.